# Plotting multiple stacked bar graph given a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

There are a few things that I would like to express in a bar chart and have no clue about doing it using basic graphing techniques in `matplotlib`. I have a dataframe which is shown below and would like to obtain a bar chart as described below. The x-axis is based on the the `Type` column of the dataframe and within a single bar, the different colors are based on the `Name` column and the size of the bar is defined by the `Count` number. The color of the different names need not to be the same across different types,
 as long as the colors within a single bar is different.[image: Example of the given dataframe]
[image: Bar chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pivot and then plot

```
df.pivot('Type', 'Name', 'Count').plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True,  color = ['b','g','orange','m', 'r'])
```

Edit: To sort the values

```
df.pivot('Type', 'Name', 'Count').sort_values(by = 'A', ascending = False, axis = 1)\
.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, color = ['g','r','b','orange', 'm'])
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to sort the bar chart in descending order of the counts?

Comment: I think I know how. I can create an extra column called 'Sum' which is the sum of the other columns and sort based on that before plotting it. Thanks a lot for your help! This works great :)

Comment: See the edit for sort and thank you for accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

I you want to change the size of plot the use arg `figsize=(15, 5)`

```
df.pivot('Type', 'Name', 'Count').sort_values(by = 'A', ascending = False, axis = 1)\
.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, color = ['g','r','b','orange', 'm'], figsize=(15,5))
```